# In Star Trek (2009) why was the Romulan mining ship medical bay full of water

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

In the film Star Trek (2009), why was the Romulan mining ship's medical bay full of water up to shin depth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have any facts to back up this answer, but looking at this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/in-star-trek-2009-what-did-the-romulans-do-for-25-years-while-waiting), I learned that Nero and the future Romulans spent 25 years on a Klingon prison planet.  During that time, I would guess no one was maintaining the ship, and if it was stored on planet, condensation would build up and pool around.

Comment: It wasn't stored on a planet, it was kept in orbit around the prison world of Rura Penthe.