# Why did Nero wait for over decade after arriving in 23rd century?

Tags: star-trek, movie, star-trek-2009

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Star Trek (2009), what did the Romulans do for 25 years while waiting?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/in-star-trek-2009-what-did-the-romulans-do-for-25-years-while-waiting)

When Nero arrived in 23rd century, Kirk wasn't even born. But, at the time of destruction of Vulcan and attack on Earth, Kirk was probably 18+.

Assuming the Black Hole was in Alpha or Beta quadarant (initial workspace of Hobus), Narada didn't need that many years to reach Vulcan & Earth. What was Nero really doing after destruction of USS Kelvin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason he waited over a decade is actually explained in the movie. It is explained by Spock to Kirk on the ice planet.

The reason for him waiting so long was because he was waiting for Spock to come through the time shift in space, Both of them were pulled into the time shift, but Spock was pulled in seconds after Nero's ship. Which meant Nero appeared years before Spock. This gave Nero plenty of time to plan what he would do. He wanted to show Spock the destruction of his home planet just like Nero had seen his.

Comment: When *Narada* got trapped by Black Hole, Spock was on-board *Narada* (according to *Star Trek: Countdown* comic series).

Comment: It's possible that Nero was waiting for Jelly Ship which had Red Matter.

Comment: Is this whole thing not answered in the latest movie. I thought it was just revenge Nero wanted that's why I was waiting. He didn't care about going home as his home had been destroyed.

Comment: @Popeye's answer is correct, Nero was waiting for Spock's arrival. There is also vague mention of a Klingon prison planet being attacked by the Narada (transmissions Uhura received), and in some interviews with JJ Abrams, he reveals there were scenes cut from the film that showed Nero being incarcerated by the Klingons... so the Narada crew may have spent some time springing their captain free.

Comment: Looks like movie hasn't been continued from where it's prequel comic series left...

Comment: @Popeye: `He didn't care about going home as his home had been destroyed.` As Pike (or was it the first ship's captian?) points out to Nero during their parlay, Romulus is very much intact at this point in time. Nero _could have_ gone home to (early) Romulus. He could've even warned them. But he didn't.